# How to extract the first column from a file with tab-separated columns

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with the following format

```
  EMAIL[TAB]NAME[TAB]ADRESSE[TAB]...
  test@test.ma[TAB]toto[TAB]tatatata....
  test@test.com[TAB]toto[TAB]tatatata....
```

[TAB] ===> tabulation

I would like with a bash script to remove all columns except the email:

the final **output** should be something like:

```
  EMAIL
  test@test.ma
  test@test.com
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use

```
cut -f1 < inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" } { print $1 }' a
```

Comment: You just received [uuoc award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)... ;-)

Comment: It's been a long time coming :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/\t.*//' yourfile
```

(The answer using `cut` would be my first choice though.)